# Delayed Image Loading (svelte/html)

Tags: javascript, image, svelte

I am making a website as a photography portfolio for someone. As a result, I want the images to load quickly and be able to scroll through them smoothly. However, when I scroll down the page the images tend to pop in instead of already being loaded. I tried to solve this with a variety of strategies but none of them seemed to work. Currently, the images are created in javascript and added to the html div when their onload function is called but the problem persists. Is there any way to fix this?

Relevant code:

```
<script>
    let imageContainer: HTMLDivElement;
    onMount(async () => {
        // FetchEntries just returns an array of objects that have urls (.imagePath)
        data = await FetchEntries();
        data.forEach((entry) => {
            let url = CDN_LOCATION + "/" + entry.imagePath;
            let newImage = new Image(500, 500);
            newImage.src = url;
            newImage.onload = () => imageContainer.append(newImage);
        });

        loaded = true;
    });
</script>

<div bind:this={imageContainer}/>
```

Gif showing the behavior:

[image]

Comment: Would you prefer to load all images first and only display them after all being loaded?

Answer (score 0):

I have been using the `fetchPriority` attribute on images directly so they are loaded eargerly in the `<img>` tag. Try implementing this to your image tag.
Find out more at the [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/fetchPriority)
Here's an example.....

```css
.flex{
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}

img{
width: 400px;
height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
<img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/58c/pancake-with-bananas-and-syrup-1641696.jpg" alt="pancake_banana" fetchPriority = "high" />

<img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/0f5/monkey-eating-banana-on-a-beach-in-krabi-thailand-1633459.jpg" alt="monkey_banana" fetchPriority = "high" />


<img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/ea1/bananas-red-1629945.jpg" alt="plain_banana" fetchPriority = "high" />

<img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/4e0/delicious-cake-1317435.jpg" alt="banana_cake" fetchPriority = "high"/>
</div>
```

Comment: I think what the question author wants is more like the opposite: Images to be loaded eagerly.